# iterating through list elements - python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have 3 list

```
list_a =['hii','hello','hai']
list_b = ['john','david']

main_list = ['list_a','list_b']
```

how can i iterate items in list_a and list_b using items in main_list ? is it possible to do in a single line.

**Desired output**

```
hii
hello
hai
john
david
```

Comment: nice question, I'm going to answer you.

Comment: So `main_list` is a list of strings of the names of the other lists, not the actual lists themselves?

Comment: This sort of question has multiple answers (the first of which is really ["you have an XY problem"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/322040)), but the various answers on [the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1373164/364696) cover all the options. In your case, using `globals()` or `locals()` would get you the `dict` that would let you look up the string names you've got.

Comment: @Aniiya0978, the post has been closed (because there was more than a question in there). You can find your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-variable-variables

Comment: Gee, not so many of those answers in the linked post answer this question. You probably want to use the `eval()` builtin to reference a variable named in a string. E.g. `for list_ in main_list: for item in eval(list_): print(item)`.

Comment: @Graham501617: `eval` is a suboptimal solution in most cases given it has to fire up the Python compiler (and might do more than just look up names); `for item in globals()[list_]:` (sub `locals()` for `globals()` if the variables are at function scope) would do the trick without that issue (it's the third-ranked answer on the dupe at time of posting).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the most "pythonic" way would be to use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
list_a =['hii','hello','hai']
list_b = ['john','david']
for name in itertools.chain(list_a, list_b):
    print(name)
```

The cool thing about this is that it works for *any* iterables, not just `list`s.  So you could combine lists, sets, an iterable of dictionary keys, a custom generator function, etc. all into one iterable.

You can also pass a list of iterables instead of variadic arguments by using [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
list_a = ['hii', 'hello', 'hai']
list_b = ['john', 'david']
main_list = [list_a, list_b]
for name in itertools.chain.from_iterable(main_list):
    print(name)
```

And if you *really* need the elements of `main_list` to be strings (protip: you probably don't):

```
main_list = ['list_a', 'list_b']
for name in itertools.chain.from_iterable(globals().get(list_name, []) for list_name in main_list):
    ...
```

Comment: What happened to `main_list`?

Comment: @PeterWood I very strongly suspect that `main_list` is unnecessary in OP's case.  But I've added an example for completeness' sake.